# Shopify Admin REST API Webhook Is Not Calling Another Server URL

Tags: api, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

I set up a webhook from admin REST API on my development server by creating an app in my store.
All the webhooks are working fine.
Now I changed my server, moved all APIs to it, and registered all the webhooks with a new server URL.
Now, I'm not getting the data from webhook. I'm not sure whether webhook is working or not.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Under your shopify.dev account if you click on your app you have the section "Insights" where it shows logs. Including webhooks logs.

Comment: But, I have not created the app from shopify partner panel, I have created it from myshopify.com account, inside settings->App and sales channel->Develop apps->create app